# Symfony 2 - access_control vs isGranted() to control access in controller

Tags: symfony, authorization, access-control

In [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) there are many examples of many ways how to manage access control for certain routes.

There I have my `access_control` block in `security.yml` where I describe which page can be accessed by which role:

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/trainee, roles: ROLE_TRAINEE }
        - { path: ^/university, roles: ROLE_UNIVERSITY_PROFESSOR }
        - { path: ^/company, roles: ROLE_COMPANY_TUTOR }
```

Now these routes can be only accessed with these `ROLES` and no other.

There in these routes I have some forms and I am wondering if `access_control` is enough for these forms not to be reached by other `ROLE`?

I saw some examples on the internet where people are puting `isGranted()` in form submission:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    if (!$authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_TRAINEE')) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

    // ...
}
```

But again here, I am not sure if they are protecting these routes from `access_control` or only from the inside of controller with `isGranted()`.

Could someone explain the difference and if I should also protect forms with `isGranted()` even tho routes are protected from `access_control`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having the access control rules is enough,   if your form is behind an uri which matches the access_control's regex  (why dont you simply test this ...?)

Comment: I was thinking that if you cannot access this page maybe it is possible to submit form using JS from outside the platform in some way? Or it is something I shouldn't worry about? I have lack of knowledge how routes are protected.

Comment: Whichever way te data is posted, if it is posted to An endpoint, which is behind te access control rule, the access control rule Will be in effect